# Actions-on-Google can not get UPDATES_USER_ID on Dialogflow SDK

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm setting up an action which uses push notifications. Yet, on firebase I can't get "UPDATES_USER_ID" of user to save. It returns "undefined".

I followed the guide on this [link](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) and here is my code to get UPDATES_USER_ID.

```
app.intent('Setup', (conv, params) => {
  conv.ask(new UpdatePermission({
    intent: "notificationResponseIntent"
    }));
});

app.intent("FinishNotificationSetup", (conv, params) => {    
  if (conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION')) {
      conv.data.GoogleUserID =  conv.arguments.get("UPDATES_USER_ID");
      console.log(conv.data.GoogleUserID);
      conv.ask("some response....");
    } 
});
```

And here is my webhook request when FinishNotificationSetup intent is invoked.

```
{
  "responseId": "2f425fe5-db42-47dc-90a1-c9bc85f725d2",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "actions_intent_PERMISSION",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/projectname/agent/sessions/ABwppHGD33Tyho41g9Mr2vzxePlskNmvOzCTxUiDGzENcl3C7RQs94aOQ8ae_DUlOApR0VBO9DuwAWdWr2frAA/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output"
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/projectname-10c22/agent/sessions/ABwppHGD33Tyho41g9Mr2vzxePlskNmvOzCTxUiDGzENcl3C7RQs94aOQ8ae_DUlOApR0VBO9DuwAWdWr2frAA/contexts/actions_intent_permission",
        "parameters": {
          "PERMISSION": true,
          "text": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/projectname-10c22/agent/sessions/ABwppHGD33Tyho41g9Mr2vzxePlskNmvOzCTxUiDGzENcl3C7RQs94aOQ8ae_DUlOApR0VBO9DuwAWdWr2frAA/contexts/_actions_on_google",
        "lifespanCount": 98,
        "parameters": {
          "data": "{\"***":\"***",\"***":\"***"}"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/projectname-10c22/agent/sessions/ABwppHGD33Tyho41g9Mr2vzxePlskNmvOzCTxUiDGzENcl3C7RQs94aOQ8ae_DUlOApR0VBO9DuwAWdWr2frAA/contexts/actions_capability_account_linking"
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/projectname-10c22/agent/sessions/ABwppHGD33Tyho41g9Mr2vzxePlskNmvOzCTxUiDGzENcl3C7RQs94aOQ8ae_DUlOApR0VBO9DuwAWdWr2frAA/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output"
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/projectname-10c22/agent/sessions/ABwppHGD33Tyho41g9Mr2vzxePlskNmvOzCTxUiDGzENcl3C7RQs94aOQ8ae_DUlOApR0VBO9DuwAWdWr2frAA/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_keyboard"
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/projectname-10c22/agent/sessions/ABwppHGD33Tyho41g9Mr2vzxePlskNmvOzCTxUiDGzENcl3C7RQs94aOQ8ae_DUlOApR0VBO9DuwAWdWr2frAA/contexts/actions_capability_web_browser"
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/projectname-10c22/agent/sessions/ABwppHGD33Tyho41g9Mr2vzxePlskNmvOzCTxUiDGzENcl3C7RQs94aOQ8ae_DUlOApR0VBO9DuwAWdWr2frAA/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio"
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/projectname-10c22/agent/intents/a12b6d3f-0f24-45e9-a1b2-5649083831b0",
      "displayName": "FinishNotificationSetup"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "tr"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "source": "google",
    "version": "2",
    "payload": {
      "isInSandbox": true,
      "surface": {
        "capabilities": [
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.ACCOUNT_LINKING"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
          }
        ]
      },
      "requestType": "SIMULATOR",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "rawInputs": [
            {
              "inputType": "KEYBOARD"
            }
          ],
          "arguments": [
            {
              "textValue": "true",
              "name": "PERMISSION",
              "boolValue": true
            },
            {
              "name": "text"
            }
          ],
          "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION"
        }
      ],
      "user": {
        "lastSeen": "2019-04-30T07:23:23Z",
        "permissions": [
          "UPDATE"
        ],
        "locale": "tr-TR",
        "userId": "ABwppHHCEdtf23ZaNg0DaCv3fvshSUXUvYGXHe6kR7jbKacwIS6vDBBL7YXbN70jYa8KaXWZqbsyhFFSdsYLiw"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "conversationId": "ABwppHGD33Tyho41g9Mr2vzxePlskNmvOzCTxUiDGzENcl3C7RQs94aOQ8ae_DUlOApR0VBO9DuwAWdWr2frAA",
        "type": "ACTIVE",
        "conversationToken": "[\"_actions_on_google\"]"
      },
      "availableSurfaces": [
        {
          "capabilities": [
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "session": "projects/projectname-10c22/agent/sessions/ABwppHGD33Tyho41g9Mr2vzxePlskNmvOzCTxUiDGzENcl3C7RQs94aOQ8ae_DUlOApR0VBO9DuwAWdWr2frAA"
}
```

To send notification, I've been using userID instead of UPDATES_USER_ID and it is working. Yet, it will be deprecated soon. So, I need to find a solution to get this ID and couldn't make it working. What do I need to do to get this ID?

Comment: Hey @snuffbox just to confirm, you responded "yes" to the prompt asking whether you wanted to get updates for this Action? Can you paste the contents of the request to your webhook for the FinishNotificationSetup intent?

Comment: Hey @SachitMishra, yes I responded yes. I've updated question and added request.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution for this problem. While getting `UPDATES_USER_ID` conv.arguments.get() only works for first attempt. So, while building your action you must save it. If you didn't store or save, you can reset your profile and try again, you will be able to get.

```
app.intent("FinishNotificationSetup", (conv, params) => {    
     if (conv.arguments.get('PERMISSION')) {
     if(!conv.user.storage.GoogleUserID)
     {
        conv.user.storage.GoogleUserID =  conv.arguments.get("UPDATES_USER_ID");
       //For best case
       //store ID in your db.
     }
     console.log(conv.user.storage.GoogleUserID);
     conv.ask("some response....");
    } 
});
```

For best case, try saving this to your database because conv.user.storage does not work sometimes.