# How to use Sign-In User ID to send push notifications

Tags: push-notification, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-signin

I have some users signed into my actions-on-google app via Google Sign-In ( https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in )

I want to sent push notifications to one of those users.

For getting push notifications work with actions in the first place, I tried this sample: https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-updates-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js but I only can get this to work without this commit: https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-updates-nodejs/commit/c655062047b49e372da37af32376bd06d837fc7f#diff-1e53ef2f51bd446c876676ba83d7c888

It works fine, but I think const userID = conv.user.id; returns the deprecated Anonymous User ID. The commit suggests to use const userID = conv.arguments.get('UPDATES_USER_ID'); which returns undefined.

I use this nodejs code to send the push notifications.

```
const request = require('request');
const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library');
const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json');
let jwtClient = new JWT(
  serviceAccount.client_email, null, serviceAccount.private_key,
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.fulfillment.conversation'],
  null
);
jwtClient.authorize((authErr, tokens) => {
  let notification = {
    userNotification: {
      title: process.argv[2],
    },
    target: {
      userId: USERID,
      intent: 'tell_latest_status',
      // Expects a IETF BCP-47 language code (i.e. en-US)
      locale: 'en-US'
    },
  };
  request.post('https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/conversations:send', {
    'auth': {
      'bearer': tokens.access_token,
    },
    'json': true,
    'body': {
      'customPushMessage': notification, 'isInSandbox': true
    },
  }, (reqErr, httpResponse, body) => {
    console.log(httpResponse.statusCode + ': ' + httpResponse.statusMessage);
  });
});
```

I simply can't get this to work with the const userID = conv.arguments.get('UPDATES_USER_ID'); version, because as I said

When I use conv.user.profile.payload.sub as suggested here: https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info the AoG API returns "SendToConversation response: Invalid user id for target."

Is there any way to make this work with Google Sign-In?
Has anyone made this work? I mean with the UPDATES_USER_ID field?

I already created an issue on the samples repo: https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-updates-nodejs/issues/15 but I was sent here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While researching why I sometimes got `undefined` I found an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55857572/actions-on-google-can-not-get-updates-user-id-on-dialogflow-sdk) that solved my issue.

> I've found solution for this problem. While getting UPDATES_USER_ID
>   conv.arguments.get() only works for first attempt. So, while building
>   your action you must save it. If you didn't store or save, you can
>   reset your profile and try again, you will be able to get.

You can reset your user profile for the action [here](https://assistant.google.com/explore/?hl=en).